# keyboard keys to add dependencies to react useEffect

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

What's the keyboard keys for to add dependencies to React useEffect array in order using Vscode on PC ?
I have tried ctrl + spacebar but that just to import.

Comment: Maybe `ctrl` + `.`?